# Enable/Disable button based on password input length with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, button

Trying to enable/disable a form button based on password input length but my code doesn't work. If the length is less than 15 characters button should be disabled.

So far my simple html form

```
<form class="form" id="form1" method="POST" action="submit.php" accept-charset="UTF-8" autocomplete="off">
   <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="passfield">
   <button type="submit" id="form-submit">CONNECT</button>
</form>
```

No username field needed in my case

and so far my Javascript code

```
function submit_btn() {

  var field = document.getElementById("passfield");
  var button = document.getElementById("form-submit");

  if (field.value.lenght < 15){
    button.setAttribute("disabled", "");
  }else{
    button.removeAttribute("disabled");
  }
};
```

Comment: First of all ".length" not ".lenght"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where do you call submit_btn?

Also spelling length

Here is a better version

```js
const field = document.getElementById("passfield");
const button = document.getElementById("form-submit");

field.addEventListener("input", function() {
  button.disabled = field.value.length < 15;
})
```

```html
<form class="form" id="form1" method="POST" action="submit.php" accept-charset="UTF-8" autocomplete="off">
  <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="passfield">
  <button type="submit" disabled id="form-submit">CONNECT</button>
</form>
```